# CAA - How to read CATIA PartBody Feature Color?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cad, catia, caa

How to read the Colour and Visiblity Details for features inside a CATPart.
In Which Container these details will be saved?  What function we have to use ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I found some info on https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/54479.

http://www.edrawingsviewer.com/ed/edrawings-publisher-catia-v5.htm have some software with an API you may be able to use.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I tried CATIVisProperties.It worked fine for Product Color details but in case of Body Query Fails.

Comment: @PreetSangha - Ya it works.For Products you can query CATIVisProperties directly.And I got color details for Body & Face also.For Body you have to query from Geometrical Element and CATIBRepAccess for faces with the help of CATBRepDecode function.

Comment: But In case of CGMContainer we ll get body from Geometries and query fails if we ask for CATIGeometricalElement.In that case am not able to  get body color details.Is there any other way ?